# In App billing Android for multi product with diff price?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I want to put multi book for salling like 500 to 1000 book for online sale in android app. but i don't know how to set diff price for diff book for sale in app billing

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create different items in your Google Play account.

For example:
books500 - for pack of 500 books
books1000 - for pack of 1000 books
and so on.

Of course each item has price.

Comment: so i need to enter every item in  google play account ?

Comment: yes, you have to define each item at GooglePlay account.